# Proof (epsilon delta) for the continuity of a function at a point

Tags: calculus, limits

#### Task

I have the following function

$f(x)=x^2+1$

I need to prove, according to the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of a limit, that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 2$.

#### Step 1

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \enspace \exists \delta > 0 : |f(x) - L| < \epsilon, \mbox{ when } 0 < |x - c| < \delta \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$.

If a function is continious at a given point, the value of the limit and the function must be equal, so:

$\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=f(c)$.

And in this case - $f(2) = 2^2 + 1 = 5$.

Which means that $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=5$.

#### Step 2

Try to define $x$ in terms of $\delta$.

$0 < |x - 2| < \delta \\
0 < x < \delta + 2$

#### Step 3

Try to define $x$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

$
|x^2+1 - 5| < \epsilon \\
4- \epsilon < x^2 < \epsilon + 4 \\
\sqrt{4- \epsilon} < x < \sqrt{\epsilon + 4}
$

#### Step 4

What next? I'm a little weak on how should I proceed.

Comment: You'd probably want to define delta (instead of x) in terms of epsilon, as your proof will contain a choice of delta (as function of epsilon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, at the end of step 2, you probably intended to write $2-\delta<x<2+\delta$.

I would approach this slightly differently, but after what you have done you want to show that given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}<x<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}$ follows from $2-\delta<x<2+\delta$. That would be the case when $\sqrt{4-\epsilon}\le 2-\delta$ and $2+\delta\le \sqrt{4+\epsilon}$.

Comment: How do you decide on the which side do you put delta and epsilon on?

Comment: There were a few typos (actually a bunch of them), I hope that it is clearer now.

Comment: Yeah, it sure is, but there's on question still, how do you decide on the ordering of $\sqrt{e-\epsilon}$ and $2 - \delta$?

Comment: Read the definition in step 1: You want that $|x - 2| < \delta$ implies $|x^2+1 - 5| < \epsilon$.